# Rcpp doesn't under macOS, math.h not found

Tags: macos, c++, r

Rcpp package doesn't run R 3.6 MacOS Mojave.

I've got the following error when I run

`Library(Rcpp)`

`evalCpp("2 + 2")`

The output is:

```
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/private/var/folders/h5/r7lh__p16wx7cg_5pzknfg5w0000gn/T/Rtmpz3QxlQ/sourceCpp-x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0-1.0.1" -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c file7d712a4a950.cpp -o file7d712a4a950.o
Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, cacheDir = cacheDir,  : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
clang: warning: no such sysroot directory: '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk' [-Wmissing-sysroot]
In file included from file7d712a4a950.cpp:1:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:29:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:59:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/platform/compiler.h:100:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:305:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/math.h:301:15: fatal error: 'math.h' file not found
#include_next <math.h>
              ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [file7d712a4a950.o] Error 1
```

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried so far to fix this?

Comment: I tried to downgrade R version but I've failed. I did google research about the clang stuff with no results. I´m not a lazy one music2myear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

macOS 10.14 does not install its header files in the old location anymore. Many third-party installations are broken unless you run:

```
sudo installer -pkg \
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg \
-target /
```

See also [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/922).

You have to repeat this command when updating R or macOS (Xcode).

Comment: Works for me. I had to install the package directly from Apple developers website. Regards

Answer (score 3):

Another solution that does not require forced installation of headers in their old location is to tell R their new location by setting the following variables in `~/.R/Makevars`:

```
CFLAGS=-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
CCFLAGS=-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
CXXFLAGS=-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
```

See https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/.

Comment: Just to add those three lines didn't work for me. I had to follow the whole procedure outlined in the link above for installing R COMPILER TOOLS FOR RCPP ON MACOS.  (https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/). But then it worked like a charm! +1 from me